# How to append to a JavaScript array dynamically?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create Javascript array(JSON format) dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-arrayjson-format-dynamically)

I am attempting to create the following:

```
var employees = {"accounting": [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                    { "firstName" : "John",  // First element
                      "lastName"  : "Doe",
                      "age"       : 23 },

                    { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                      "lastName"  : "Smith",
                      "age"       : 32 }
                  ] // End "accounting" array.                                  

    } // End Employees
```

I started out with:

```
 var employees=new Array();
```

How do I continue to append to the array dynamically (might change firstName with variable)?

Comment: even the description is same... as above duplicate question!

Comment: The fact that you've received 5 upvotes for this question and [9 upvotes on this **identical question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-arrayjson-format-dynamically) is *extremely* suspicious.

Answer (score 7):

```
var employees = {accounting: []};

employees.accounting.push({
    "firstName" : "New",
    "lastName"  : "Employee",
    "age"       : 18
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Will accept in a few minutes

Comment: On a side note there is good reason so many JavaScripters use array literals besides just their terseness, the variadic signature of new Array() is confusing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
Notice that if you pass a single Number it interprets it as a default length for the array, where if you pass two Numbers, it treats it like the first two elements of the array.

Comment: _"the variadic signature of new Array() is confusing"_ - And in this case `employees` isn't even supposed to be an array, it's an object...

Answer (score 2):

```
employees.accounting.push({ "firstName" : "New",  // First element
                      "lastName"  : "Person",
                      "age"       : 55 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var urNewFirstName='new john';
employees.accounting[0].firstName = urNewFistName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Employee(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
}

var employees = {};
employees.accounting = [];
employees.accounting.push(new Employee('John', 'Doe', 23));
employees.accounting.push(new Employee('Mary', 'Smith', 32));
```