# aoColumnDefs data in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTables to populate some data on my page, I have come to a point where everything works fine except i am unable to hide sorting arrow for one of the column.

I need to use `aoColumnDefs` parameter to accompolish any column level task.

When i hardcode `"aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [2]}]`, sorting arrow gets hidden/disabled from column[2], As i am using HTML5 and passing every parameter from HTML to make my whole DataTable generic, I need to pass this `aoColumnDefs` through variables.

I have tried this

`var mSortingString = [];

            var disableSortingColumn = "2";
            mSortingString.push({ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [disableSortingColumn] });`

and then assigning this `mSortingString` string as value to `aoColumnDefs` but that doesnt seems to work. I can see `mSortingString` having above data but that doesn't disable sorting arrows. Another thing is as I have given variable `disableSortingColumn` value of 2, but in `mSortingString` array, its 1.

Can anyone help me in right direction, I think its my minimal knowledge of Javascript.

Have tried looking at this [Create JavaScript array (JSON format) for DataTables aoColumnDefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311420/create-javascript-array-json-format-for-datatables-aocolumndefs) but this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"2" is a string, and DataTables wants an int.  So make it

```
var disableSortingColumn = 2;
```

And it should work.  I created a jsFiddle for it, fwiw.   http://jsfiddle.net/CYcc2/