# How to form JavaScript object array?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JavasScript array in following format:

```
var datas = [
    { name: "Peter Pan", location: "peter@pan.de" },
    { name: "Molly", location: "molly@yahoo.com" },
    { name: "Forneria Marconi", location: "live@japan.jp" },
    { name: "Master <em>Sync</em>", location: "205bw@samsung.com" }
];
```

As I want to create it dynamically, It would be great if I can create an array like that.

Comment: That code you posted does create a JavaScript array.  What do you mean "dynamically"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = [];
data.push({ name: "Peter Pan", location: "peter@pan.de" },
    { name: "Molly", location: "molly@yahoo.com" },
    { name: "Forneria Marconi", location: "live@japan.jp" },
    { name: "Master <em>Sync</em>", location: "205bw@samsung.com" });
```

If you are receiving the object from some service, just call `data.push(objectName);`. You will have array of objects.

Fiddle for you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/q69ku/

Answer (score 3):

You just did it.

But if you mean adding objects one at a time you can do

```
var datas = [];
```

and then

```
newobj = //dynamically created object

datas.push(newobj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:
[How do I create JavaScript array (JSON format) dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-arrayjson-format-dynamically)

```
var data = [];
data.push({ name: "Peter Pan", location: "peter@pan.de" });
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.push({name: "x" location:"y"})`

Answer (score 2):

you will need to change this to fit your data results

```
 var arr = [];
    var b = 20; // or your data results
    for(i=0;i<b;i++){
        var obj = {name: "Peter Pan", location: "peter@pan.de"};
    arr.push(obj);
    }
```