# Convert array to objects using JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need convert arrays inside my parent array to objects to match my database model data.

I have array like this:

```
emails: Array[2] 
0: "example@mail.com"
1: "otherexample@mail.com"
id: 1 
firstname: "Jane"
lastname: "Doe
```

What I want to achieve is to convert emails array to array of objects like this:

```
    emails: Array[2] 
    0: 
{
name: "example@mail.com"
}
    1: 
{
name: "otherexample@mail.com"
}
    id: 1 
    firstname: "Jane"
    lastname: "Doe
```

I tried to use this code to convert array to object but for some reason it fails (no data are displayed -> variable rv is empty):

```
 var rv = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < dbInfo.emails.length; ++i)
            if (dbInfo.emails[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = dbInfo.emails[i];
```

Does someone knows why my code fails and does someone knows solution for this type of problem?

Thanks advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-arrayjson-format-dynamically

Comment: this code doesn't end up with `rv` being empty, unless `dbInfo.emails` is empty. I just tested it.

Comment: I can't even make sense of the way the OP has presented the desired input and output

Comment: Is the goal here to store the name and multiple email addresses for a user? If so, the data structure should be changed. The `id`, `firstname` and `lastname` properties are fine, but you should have an `email` property that is an array, containing the multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a perfect use for the `Array.prototype.map` function:

```
dbInfo.emails = dbInfo.emails.map(function(e) {
    return { name: e };
});
```

i.e. just convert each individual element of the array (`e`) into an object `{ name: email }`

Answer (score 5):

I think what are you looking for was angular.extend. For a good article about angular.extend click  [here](http://moduscreate.com/angularjs-tricks-with-angular-extend/). For documentation click  [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) .

```
var newObj = {};
angular.extend(newObj,[Array here]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the emails into an object. Instead, you want to wrap each email in its own object, and put it back in the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dbInfo.emails.length; ++i) {
    if(dbInfo.emails[i] !== undefined) {
        dbInfo.emails[i] = { name: dbInfo.emails[i] };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work perfectly
  //Option Select

```
  var range = [];
    for (var i=1; i<$scope.totalItems+1; i++) {
      range.push({value:i});
    }  

  console.log(range);
```