# Convert an array into object boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array `["one","two","three"]` would like to convert it into this `{one:true, two:true, three:true}`. Basically what am doing is converting the array items to keys of an object and make them boolean. I have tried using spread operator `{... arr}` which results to `{0:'one',1:'two',2:'three'}`, Any Ideas?

Comment: @mplungjan Both the questions aren't dupe.

Comment: @mplungjan it't duplicate I had gone through the question and it was not solving my issue.

Comment: @praveen kumar but this is an exact dupe ... And I'm surprised no one here found it ...

Comment: @JonasW. I did. Praveen reopened

Comment: @JonasW. That's now an exact dupe... Not the one before...

Comment: @JonasW. The other dupe was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694873/convert-array-to-objects-using-javascript-angularjs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could map objects and assign them to a single object.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: come on. standard code with standard features.

Comment: I prefer the reduce by pointy because there is no extra conversion. You use both assign and destructuring for something simple, just to avoid the object initialisation. Then I have to go with Pointy's `var object = array.reduce((m, v) => (m[v] = true, m), {});`

Comment: This is also standard code with standard features: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/q5e3d8cu/ :P

Comment: mplungjan  can you please explain why it works???

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.reduce()`:

```
var object = array.reduce((m, v) => (m[v] = true, m), {});
```

The callback function could be written as a traditional function too:

```
var object = array.reduce(function(m, v) {
  m[v] = true;
  return m;
}, {});
```

The `.reduce()` function passes each value in the array (`v` in the sample code above) to the callback, along with an "accumulator" value. The callback function can do whatever it wants to the accumulator, and then it should return it.  The second argument to `.reduce()` is the initial value of the accumulator, in this case a new empty object.

Comment: Why reduce over a simple forEach? Saving the object initialisation?

Comment: @mplungjan because then I don't need a separate declaration for the target object. I personally always prefer a solution that can be written as a single expression. Of course one could wrap a `.forEach()` or even a simple `for` loop in an IIFE but that seems messy.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object which is also yours

Comment: @mplungjan lol :) — well it's *mostly* a duplicate I guess, except for the value requirement here. But I don't contest closing it of course.

Comment: more lol here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/q5e3d8cu/

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a `forEach`.

```js
var keys = ["one","two","three"];
var obj = {};
keys.forEach(function (v) {
  obj[v] = true;
});
console.log(obj);
```