# Add value in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
var labels = ["Hat", "Chair", "Pen"];
```

and I want the output

```
var output = {"Hat": true, "Chair": true, "Pen": true};
```

how to convert this in javascript

Thanks

Comment: The second `labels` output should be object, right? It's invalid array now.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid javascript syntax.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+convert+array+to+object+of+boolean+properties) of [Convert an array into object boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003654/4642212).

Comment: ```
var output = labels.reduce((output, label) => { output[label] = true; return output}, {})   
```

Comment: @A.DUPONCHEL That’s not how reducer functions work. You’re not returning the aggregator object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var labels = ["Hat", "Chair", "Pen"];
let labelsObject = {};
labels.forEach(label => {
  labelsObject[label] = true;
})

console.log(labelsObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var labels = ["Hat", "Chair", "Pen"];

const obj = labels.reduce((acc,e) => {
  acc[e] = true;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```