# How to create JSON array..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am creating a localStorage variable and always push data to it where I am collecting.

Here is my data set and it is dynamically generating.

```
{ 'my_id' : '79', 'cc_id' : '57223' }, { 'my_id' : '79', 'cc_id' : '57249' }, { 'my_id' : '79', 'cc_id' : '57250' }, { 'my_id' : '79', 'cc_id' : '57221' }, { 'my_id' : '79', 'cc_id' : '57220' }
```

I need to convert this to a json array.

How could I do so. I tried but couldn't find out a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string) If you check out the answer to that question, you'll see there is a built-in method in JavaScript to convert objects and arrays to JSON.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-arrayjson-format-dynamically

Comment: @forgivenson This is not a duplicate question and I searched in the link you provided too and tried the ways on it before ask this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surround your data with `[` and `]`.

Also single quotes are not allowed, only double quotes.

So here, what you'll have:

```
[ { "my_id" : "79", "cc_id" : "57223" }, { "my_id" : "79", "cc_id" : "57249" }, { "my_id" : "79", "cc_id" : "57250" }, { "my_id" : "79", "cc_id" : "57221" }, { "my_id" : "79", "cc_id" : "57220" } ]
```