# building JSON string in angular from form

Tags: angularjs, json, post, build

currently i have an api in which you send a json and the api response: 
the json i send: `{
  "instructions": [
    {
      "A": 9,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveonto"
    },
    {
      "A": 8,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveover"
    }
  ],
  "length": 20,
  "res": "null"
}`

and the api response: `{
  "instructions": [
    {
      "A": 9,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveonto"
    },
    {
      "A": 8,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveover"
    }
  ],
  "length": 20,
  "res": "Position [0] :  0Position [1] :  1 9 8Position [2] :  2Position [3] :  3Position [4] :  4Position [5] :  5Position [6] :  6Position [7] :  7Position [8] : Position [9] : Position [10] :  10Position [11] :  11Position [12] :  12Position [13] :  13Position [14] :  14Position [15] :  15Position [16] :  16Position [17] :  17Position [18] :  18Position [19] :  19"
}`

im developing a very basic webpage: 
[image: My Webpage]
when i click on the send to the server button i need to send it, the problem is i dont know how to build the json, can you help me? thx

i have slight idea:

```
Json = {
  "instructions": [{
    "A": $scope.addA,
    "B": $scope.addB,
    "move": $scope.addMov
  }, {
    "A": $scope.addA,
    "B": $scope.addB,
    "move": $scope.addMov
  }],
  "length": $scope.blockLength,
  "res": null
};
```

and i send it :

```
$http.post("http://localhost:56493/api/BlocksProblem", Json)
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.result = data;
  }, function (response) {
    $scope.result = response;
  });
```

thank you very much for your time reading through all of it.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

You dont necessarily "build" the json in the typical sense. By sending object data, angularjs with convert it to json for you.

for example. If i have a javascript variable like this:

```
var J = {A:1, B:2}
```

and send it as data in an http post, the json would look like:
{"A":"1","B":"2"}

Without seeing anything of what your server architecture looks like, you could do something like this

```
 $scope.SendJson = function (Callback) {

    $http({
        url: YOURURL,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "instructions": [
                 {"A": $scope.addA,"B": $scope.addB,"move": $scope.addMov}, 
                 {"A": $scope.addA,"B": $scope.addB,"move": $scope.addMov}],
          "length": $scope.blockLength,
          "res": null}
     })
     .then(function (data) {
               $scope.result = data;
            }, function (response) {
                 $scope.result = response;
            });

    })
```

Also, you dont need to quote the key value. Its implicit

With all that said, verify that the packet is constructed correctly in your developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

reading through stackoverflow i found this:

[How do I create JavaScript array (JSON format) dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-array-json-format-dynamically)

so i build mine with:

```
    //here i save the values of A,B and the moves, that i get from the form 
    var serverMove = [];
    var serverA = [];
    var serverB = [];
    //create the json 
    var jsonS = {
          instructions: [],
          "length": $scope.blockLength,
          "res": ""
    };
       //dynamically  fill only the instrucions array part 
        for (var i = 0; i < serverA.length; i++) {
          jsonS.instructions.push({
            "A": serverA[i],
            "B": serverB[i],
            "move": serverMove[i]
          })
        }
```

the result json is something like :

```
{ 
    "instructions": [
        { 
            "A": 1
            , "B": 3,
            "move": 
            "moveonto" 
        },
        { 
            "A": 5,
            "B": 9, 
            "move": "pileover" 
        } 
        ], 
        "length": 22, 
        "res": "" 
}
```

i hope someone finds it useful